# Why do we use 겠 and not 갰, any rational explanation?

Tags: word-usage

As I always make mistake with ㅔ and ㅐ, I always wondered why we use 겠 and not 갰, like in 알겠습니다.

Also, if there is any heuristic for ㅔ and ㅐ, please let me know.

Comment: I don't think an etymology is known, but "갰" doesn't appear in Standard Korean in any occasion.

Comment: Note that ㅔ and ㅐ are also different sounds in strictly standard Korean, and they are still quite different outside the Seoul / Gyeonggi-do areas.

Comment: wow, this is really new to me. I thought they sound the same. I will look into it later or if you could hint me where to look, I would be grateful

Comment: 갰 is used in 갰다, past tense for 개다 - to fold.

Comment: And though ㅔ and ㅐ should sound differently, even native Koreans can't tell differences between these two in everyday conversations. (They do know how to pronounce them differently, they just don't because it's a bit tedious) They are strictly differentiated in written languages, though; 네 means "your", and 내 means "my".

Comment: It has been said that -겠- came from the abbreviation for -게 ᄒᆞ엿- [(reference)](https://academic.naver.com/article.naver?doc_id=77880393).

Comment: ok thanks, I c now

Comment: read and read - `i like to read books i've read before`.  ain't no heuristic for that except `context`.  and via `context` we know how to `spell something correctly`.  note that 에 is a contraction of 어 + 이.  if that helps during the breakdown of things that natives _never_ think about...and mostly know how to spell, but occasionally 원숭이도 떨어질 때가 있다. (대 not 데 cause _**that's a different word yo**_)

Answer (score 1):

'겠' came from '게 하여 있'. So the original form of '하겠다' is '하게 하여 있다'. Of course, the latter form is not actually used in modern Korean neither in written nor in spoken form.